# Integral for the configurational part of the canonical partition function (classical monatomic gas)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, vectors, integration, gas

S. Salinas, *Introduction to Statistical Physics* (p. 111) computes the following integral for the configurational part of the canonical partition function of a classical monatomic gas (volume $V$, temperature $T$), here $f(r)=e^{-{\cal V}(r)/(k_BT)}-1$, $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, ${\cal V}(r)$ is the intermolecular potential:
$$\iint f(|{\bf r_1}-{\bf r_2}|)\text{d}^3{\bf r_1}\text{d}^3{\bf r_2}=4\pi V\int f(r)r^2 \text{d}r \qquad $$

Could someone please explain how such vectorial integrals are computed, or supply a reference which works out the above ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $\mathbf{r_i}$ denotes the 3-dimensional Cartesian coordinates of $i$th particle, so we treat it as the usual Cartesian variables. The transition from the left side equation to the right side equation is a change of variable. To accomplish this, imagine fixing $\mathbf{r_1}$ and varying $\mathbf{r_2}$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Under a change of variable to spherical coordinate, it is equivalent to varying $r$ from $0$ to $\infty$, $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$ as well as $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ from the fixed point $\mathbf{r_1}$. Since the potential only depends on the radial coordinate from $\mathbf{r_1}$, we get the $4\pi$ from the full solid angle and only the radial coordinate integration is left. Then we complete the integration of $\mathbf{r_1}$ to get $V$. Under the change of variables, following the notation of Salinas, $f_{12}$ is transformed into $f(r)$.

Note: In your question, the integrand in the left-hand side equation should be written as $f(|\mathbf{r_1}-\mathbf{r_2}|)$ to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you. Equation modified as suggested.